# Parsing a JSON like text using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing

I have a requirement to Parse a XML Text field in Oracle to remove Specific Characters/Strings in the data.

I/p:-

```
{{Value : "Actual: 15' 0" X 7' 0"  Opening:  15' 0" X 7' 0"", Description : "Size", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 80}, 
{Value : "Section Color: Desert Tan-,Trim Board Color: White", Description : "Color", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 90}, 
{Value : "Top Section: Standard-,Board Width: Standard", Description : "Design Modifications", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 100},
{Value : "Size: 2"-,Mount: Bracket  Mount-,Radius: 15"", Description : "Track", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 110},
{Value : "Springs: Standard-,Drums: Standard-,Shaft: 16 Gauge Tube", Description : "Counterbalance", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 120},
{Value : "Hinge: Standard-,Struts: Standard", Description : "Hardware", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 130}}
```

I need the O/P like -

```
"Actual: 15' 0" X 7' 0"  Opening:  15' 0" X 7' 0"", Description : "Size",
"Section Color: Desert Tan-,Trim Board Color: White", Description : "Color",
"Top Section: Standard-,Board Width: Standard", Description : "Design Modifications", 
"Size: 2"-,Mount: Bracket  Mount-,Radius: 15"", Description : "Track",
"Springs: Standard-,Drums: Standard-,Shaft: 16 Gauge Tube", Description : "Counterbalance",
"Hinge: Standard-,Struts: Standard", Description : "Hardware"
```

1) I would like to remove all the brackets.
2) I would like to remove all the code that starts with `PrintCode` until the bracket end.
3) Should replace `value :` string with null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Use a regexp_replace if this field is stored as a varchar

Comment: Which Oracle version? Is it a column in your table? What is it's datatype? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This text has nothing to do with XML, it looks more like JSON

Comment: Wernfried is righ, that input is not even remotely valid XML (it's similar to JSON but isn't valid JSON either)

Comment: Hi @Kaushik Nayak  - Oracle Version is 12C and the  datatype is Varchar. I have tried to write multiple updates to this column using REGEXP_replace function and didn't achieved the desired o/p so far.

Comment: So, is there a new line in your text after }, or just space?

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak Just space Kaushik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/388)

The pattern matches for the curly braces - `{}` *or* `value :` *or* `PrintCode until the bracket end` and replaces it with blanks. Additional `trims` are needed to remove `,` and space. `.+?` is for non-greedy match that searches until first occurrence of next character(`}` in this case).

I hope there are no new lines in the code as you said in the comments. The results could be different otherwise and the `n` Pattern-Matching option could be used to handle it.

**Query 1**:

```
WITH t ( input ) AS
  (SELECT '{{Value : "Actual: 15'' 0" X 7'' 0"  Opening:  15'' 0" X 7'' 0"", Description : "Size", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 80}, {Value : "Section Color: Desert Tan-,Trim Board Color: White", Description : "Color", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 90}, {Value : "Top Section: Standard-,Board Width: Standard", Description : "Design Modifications", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 100},{Value : "Size: 2"-,Mount: Bracket  Mount-,Radius: 15"", Description : "Track", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 110},{Value : "Springs: Standard-,Drums: Standard-,Shaft: 16 Gauge Tube", Description : "Counterbalance", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 120},{Value : "Hinge: Standard-,Struts: Standard", Description : "Hardware", PrintCode : "", PrintSequence : 130}}'
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT RTRIM ( TRIM ( REGEXP_REPLACE (input,'({|}|Value +:|PrintCode.+?}(,|}))', '')) ,',') AS output
FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/388/0)**:

`"Actual: 15' 0" X 7' 0"  Opening:  15' 0" X 7' 0"", Description : "Size",   "Section Color: Desert Tan-,Trim Board Color: White", Description : "Color",   "Top Section: Standard-,Board Width: Standard", Description : "Design Modifications",  "Size: 2"-,Mount: Bracket  Mount-,Radius: 15"", Description : "Track",  "Springs: Standard-,Drums: Standard-,Shaft: 16 Gauge Tube", Description : "Counterbalance",  "Hinge: Standard-,Struts: Standard", Description : "Hardware"`

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked out really well.